# SPWeb.EnsureUser Get SPUser object when user does not exists in AD anymore

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, active-directory

Using web.ensureuser, may I know is there a way to still retrieve the SPUser object when the user does not exist in the AD anymore?

Or can I recreate the SPUser object?

```
foreach (var requestUser in requestUsers)
{
    var item = requestUserList.Items.Add();
    bool allowUnsafeUpdate = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
    try
    {
        if (!allowUnsafeUpdate)
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        }
            requestUser.User = web.EnsureUser(requestUser.LoginId); <---dead here

            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdate;

    finally
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdate;
    }

    var userProfile = UserProfile.GetUserProfile(requestUser.User);

    item[OUASSharedMailboxRequestUserInternalName.RequestId] = requestIdLookup;
    item[OUASSharedMailboxRequestUserInternalName.User] = requestUser.User;
    item[OUASSharedMailboxRequestUserInternalName.PermissionType] = requestUser.PermissionType;
    item[OUASSharedMailboxRequestUserInternalName.EmployeeId] = new SPFieldLookupValue(userProfile.ID, userProfile.EmployeeId);
    item[OUASSharedMailboxRequestUserInternalName.LoginId] = requestUser.LoginId;
    item[OUASSharedMailboxRequestUserInternalName.Action] = requestUser.Action;
    item[OUASSharedMailboxRequestUserInternalName.Status] = requestUser.Status;

    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    item.Update();
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```

[image]

---

UPDATE: I was suggested to use the following:

```
requestUser.User = web.EnsureUser[requestUser.LoginId];
```

There are still some errors during the validations, and I'm currently resolving them.

Q: Are there any workarounds if the user does not exist in the AD as well as the SP List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following line of code to get the site user.

```
SPUser user = web.AllUsers.Cast<SPUser>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.LoginName.Contains("domain\\username"));
```

Comment: thank you for the advice, I will try this. However, will this work too if the user does not exist in the SP list?